# How add sitemesh3 namespace to jsp?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xml-namespaces, sitemesh

According to the post http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.sitemesh.sitemesh3.general/137 sitemesh3 does not tied to jsp. So there is no tag library associated with sitemesh3 tags. Any workarounds?

How I can add sitemesh3 namespace to jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like `<sitemesh:write property='title' />` and it should work.

Comment: Yes it work, but IDE like Intellij Idea underline the tag as it wrong. I want something that will underline wrong tag like <sitemesh_with_typo_> and do not underline correct tags.